# using bash to execute a group of commands from C without storing them in a file

Tags: c, linux, bash

I've got a program which accepts a set of rules in the form of a single rules file.

When one of the conditions are considered met by my program, I seek to treat the block of commands associated with the condition as an independent bash script which needs to be executed. I would rather not deal with storing these commands in files as that leaves an undesirable attack vector. Is there a way to feed a line delimited list of bash commands to bash as a single group? I want if conditions and other things from the bash script to function correctly, not just executing each line raw on its own.

Example rules file:

```
if CONDITION
some nice
bash commands
pkill some process
./launching something!
endif
```

I want to be able to run the four lines of bash code as a group of bash commands, not independently of each other, when CONDITION is true, as determined by my C program.

Obviously this is from Linux, using C as the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to use `sh -c "string containing commands to be executed"`.  What's tricky is the embedded newlines.  If the commands themselves won't contain single quotes, then you can wrap that multi-line string in single quotes.  If it can contain single quotes, you'd want to escape the string to ensure that they are unchanged.

So:

- read the commands into a buffer
- do escape processing on the buffer; replace each `'` with `'\''` (remembering that the backslash must be in the output, so the string in C looks like `"'\\''"`)
- format the command: `snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "sh -c '%s'", escaped_buffer);`
- ensure there was enough room
- run `system(command);`

Comment: that sounds like a workable solution. I'm almost to the point where I will actually have to implement that section, so I won't know until then, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also perhaps `popen` a `bash` process.

However, your approach suggests also to embed some scripting interpreter inside your application. Did you consider embedding e.g. [lua](http://www.lua.org/) inside it?